# Solution Mysql Random query migrate when goto another page

Tags: php, mysql

I have table Post, user can search Post by find by keyword.

So, i using SQL query by like keyword and order by RAND().
When show result, i using GridView and Pagination data. And has problem, when go to another page. Example from page 1 go to page 2 with same keyword. i Will Query again and order by Rand(). So some data in page 1 can appear in page 2. 
That data duplicate and not good.

So how can i solve this problem. and data query when goto page other will same with data in the first query.

I using Yii2 in my project.

Comment: Well, you limit the query to (for example) 20 results and use `ORDER BY RAND()`, right? But in MySQL, `ORDER` is applied before `LIMIT`, so you always get random results and then you limit them, that's why some of them appear in other pages. Byt the way, why do you need to use `RAND()`? It is not recommended when you want to use pages for results.

Comment: Yes, client require for random data. And require query all data. I found the solution for random item. i not using mysql random. When query data, i not using random, and when show result to user will random by php. and when access again. i will random same rule in first page. So i don't know exact php funtion for random array with same result ( add by some condition)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get it. Example MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE name LIKE '%tag%' LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Or you can use MySQL's `MATCH()` instead of `LIKE`, it doesn't matter. Then `LIMIT 0, 20` is limit, how many results to show for the first page. For the second page it should be `LIMIT 1, 20`. This one you know I except. Then you get an array of results in the PHP, and want to get random values. PHP has such a function for you and it is called **[suffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)**.

So you just use `shuffle($results);` and then you can print them with foreach or whatever you use to print the data. Note that `shuffle()` returns boolean, so do not use `$results = shuffle($results);`. Hope this helps.

Comment: that solution, not using rand() in mysql. So have problem, client need Select all data and random. As your suggest, some data(id from 0 -> 20 ) allway appear first. So how item N need appear first? And have PHP function for random array with same result? Example random first page same random in next page.

Comment: Then this is probably not possible, since visiting new page will send a new query. When you will use `RAND()`, you will always get a problem like in the question. One solution is to save IDs from first page and then disable them from another queries, which is very very wrong solution. Another can be catch all the results and use pagination with JavaScript, but this will be huge impact on the performance with a lot of results.

Comment: Yes, i think it not possible. So i have solution about caching data. When first accest page, i query data and store cache and assign with key , then access another page, i will send will key and receive data from cache.

Comment: Yes, right, that would be way, but remember, caching a huge data will slow down your website.

Comment: yes, i using file cache, and have cron job for delete cache every day.

Comment: Oh ok, that will be effective. Good luck with coding then.